# Does the inequality $\Bbb E \left[ \frac{1}{\tan(x)} \right] \leq \frac{1}{\tan(\Bbb E[x])}$ hold?

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Given a random variable $x$ and expectation $\Bbb E$, does the following inequality hold?

$$\Bbb E \left[ \frac{1}{\tan(x)} \right] \leq \frac{1}{\tan(\Bbb E[x])}$$

Comment: Of course NOT true in general. $\cot(x)$ is convex and concave in different regions. The inequality will hold if $x$ in intervals where it is concave. Otherwise, the reverse inequality will hold good, thanks to Jensen.